# flutter:how to flex several widgets when keyboard is coming

Tags: flutter, dart

i wanna when keyboard is coming up flex the widgets out my problem is this
my loginpage
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mly1K.png)

and my problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTKYv.png)

Comment: Please include the code in your question.

Comment: my code is very board can i share that?

Comment: i think there is a widget for that like expanded or flexible to do that

Comment: Just share the minimal relevant part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SingleChildScrollView` to avoid this problem.

Comment: i want show the button eaither

Comment: i think there is a widget for that like expanded or flexible

Comment: @WeißSchneider SingleChildScrollView is the correct answer. If you want to remove the button from the widget tree at the same time that is a different question.